# How is this Golbez fight possible?

Tags: final-fantasy-4

Golbez is the big bad guy so far in FF4, and now I have to fight him for the first time. This fight is...unforgiving, to say the least (horribly designed and meant to make people stop playing, more like).

At one point, he automatically kills Yang, Rosa, and Kain, before Rydia rejoins (with barely enough HP to survive an attack). Cecil and Rydia are your only remaining living party members, and all of Rydia's offensive ability heals Golbez instead of damaging him.

Golbez then proceeds to spam AoE attacks as fast as you get actions. If you use a phoenix down or Raise to heal a fallen ally, then they *immediately* die before you can take any other action.

How in the world is this battle supposed to be winnable? How can I get past this stupid thing and just get on with the game?

Comment: Which platform are you playing on?

Comment: I'm playing on DS. It's really frustrating how this version is so very similar in most ways but different in such crucial ways other times. I'm not sure when it's necessary to disclose the platform in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DS remake suffers from [Sequel Difficulty Spike](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SequelDifficultySpike), especially regarding the fight against Golbez (he turned from a pushower to a brick wall). You need luck and strategy to beat him (more luck than strategy).

Try to slow Golbez with Rosa. This makes the fight a bit more manageable, because you have a bit more time.

Try to time Kains jump, so that he is in the air when Golbez (or his pet) starts to pick off your party one by one (except Cecil).

Rydia should show up and now the real fight begins. Golbez will use barrier change, wich makes him absorb all magic except for one type. You can see his weakness by using Libra.

But before you do that, try to get your party up. Start with Rosa - Phoenix down + Hi-Potion. As soon as she is up, have her dual cast shell and Cura on the group. If you don't have dual cast, just cure the party.

Now is the time to use Libra. Expose Golbez weakness and attack with with Rydias summon. After the hit, Golbez will change his elemental weakness, so use Libra again (and don't forget to heal!!).

Golbez also likes to drain your MP - don't be afraid to use an Ether or two. Also remember to keep him slowed. Kain can either heal or use his Cry.

Comment: "dual cast"? Is this a thing I don't know about?

Comment: Dualcast is an augment ability added in the DS version. It is obtained by speaking with the Mysidian Elder if you gave three augment abilities to Palom and Porom before they leave the party, with each twin having at least one ability each. Dualcast is compatible with Black and White Magic, but not with Summon Magic.

Comment: Definitely don't have that, although it would be *really* useful right now.

Answer (score -3):

You should honestly just level up to like 50. That’s what I did and it was a singe.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade! I'm not sure that this really addresses the question. If you'd like, you can update your answer to include more helpful information, such as a solid strategy to beat him.